# Book suggestions on B-spline method for solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, spline

I am a beginner level at B-splines method. I want to solve ODEs and PDEs by this method(or other splines).
Could you suggest me an elementary book for solving partial (and ordinary) differential equations?
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: There's a number of papers on the topic (not necessarily b-splines, sometimes other kinds of splines). You could try to search for "spline collocation methods", because usually splines are used together with collocation (so that the equation is fulfilled exactly at certain points)

Comment: There's this book on splines for PDEs http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9781119301066, however I haven't been able to read it myself yet. One advantage is the use of R for demonstrations since it's open souce free software